# Always got Formula parse error when trying to use QUERY function on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to select certain data from responses of a form on a google sheet. I just want to select all the data if one cell is equal to a specific word. I've created a new sheet inside the same archive, and tried with several formulas:

```
=QUERY("respuestas!A2:M50","select * where G = 'Felino'")
```

setting name **range respuestas!A2:M50 = raw**:

```
=QUERY(raw,"select * where G = 'Felino'")
```

importing range:

```
=QUERY(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y1WxrJ9ErkqX1gR5su37dAPe97fI9KZoeQtxhuSC2lA/edit","respuestas!A2:M50"),"select * where G = 'Felino'")
```

importing range with name range:

```
=QUERY(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y1WxrJ9ErkqX1gR5su37dAPe97fI9KZoeQtxhuSC2lA/edit","respuestas!A2:M50"),"select * where G = 'Felino'")
```

and trying with Col1 attribute instead Column name, like A2, in the select property. Also trying to select just a column like:

```
"select A"
```

or

```
"select Col1""
```

and none of these works...

I dont know what else to try??

Comment: What is your locale? Have you tried `;` instead of `,` between your parameters?

Comment: The first one should be `=QUERY(respuestas!A2:M50, "select * where G = 'Felino'")`, no quotation mark around the range.  The importrange version can only work with Col1. But if no query work at all, maybe indeed you switched the locale and  need to use semicolons for separating arguments.

Comment: The semicolon works! thanx

Answer (score 5):

Ohh that works!!

Thanx...

It was just the semicolon... I've replaced ":" with ";"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your locale, you might need to use a semicolon instead of a comma to separate arguments to the `QUERY` function.

This version was *not* working for me:

```sql
=QUERY(rows, "SELECT B, D")
```

While this version did work:

```sql
=QUERY(rows; "SELECT B, D")
```

Comment: The answer from @AuriellePerlmann solved it for me, too, but since it is in a comment, and the accepted answer from OP mentions a replacement that is not what worked for me, I have put my solution in a separate answer ... Thanks to both!